# Koch snowflake in Haskell (CodeWorld)

Tags: haskell, codeworld

Through the `Haskell` package, `CodeWorld` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/codeworld-api) , I need to draw Koch's snowflake.

You can use this package online, in case you don't want to download it:  https://code.world/#

A link so you can see what I need to do:  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Von_Koch_curve.gif

I'm not quite sure how it would be done, can you help me?

And if by the way, you know some manuals to work with this package, well much better.

I've done this:

```
import CodeWorld

main :: IO ()
main = drawingOf triangle

triangle :: Picture
triangle = polygon [(9,9),(0,-9),(-9,9)]
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried the first triangle.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48365642/edit) your post to include what you've done so far.

Comment: @hnefatl I just have edited

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774395/koch-snowflake-implementation-in-haskell?rq=1

Comment: @icc97  No, because he does the exercise with monads and I need to do it with CodeWorld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer in the most general terms, because I'm not going to do your homework for you.

You need a type to represent a line between two points. You need a function that takes one line and returns 4, where the new 4 lines are the

```
_/\_
```

pattern of the Koch snowflake. Then you need a recursive function to call it to the right depth.

Comment: Do you know any manual to see examples o the defined functions?

Comment: I think you need to figure that out yourself. Start with the geometry and then translate it into Haskell.